Group By Two Variables and then Create New Column which is the Value of One Variable Based on the Value of Another Variable in Python (pandas)
I can do this in R but have no idea how to do this in Python.
I have data with sbj, num_item, visit, and height.  I want to create baseline_height using pandas.
Ex:



sbj
num_item
visit
height
baseline_height




1
1
Baseline
1.5
1.5


1
1
Day 7
2
1.5


1
1
Day 14
2.5
1.5


1
2
Baseline
1
1


1
2
Day 7
1.5
1


1
2
Day 14
2
1


2
1
Baseline
0.5
0.5


2
1
Day 7
1
0.5


2
1
Day 14
1.5
0.5


2
2
Baseline
3
3


2
2
Day 7
3.5
3


2
2
Day 14
4
3



I want to group by two variables, sbj and num_item.  I want to create a new column called baseline_height.  For each sbj and num_item combination, I want to set baseline_height to be the value of height at baseline.
I tried so many different things and none of them worked:
df['baseline_height'] = df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item']).height[['visit' == "Baseline"]]

    df['baseline_height'] = 0
    df = df.loc[df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item'])['baseline_height'].apply('visit' == 'Baseline') == df['height']]

    df['baseline_height'] = df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item']).apply(['height'][['visit'] == 'Baseline'])

    df['baseline_height'] = df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item']).apply(df['height'][df["visit"]=='Baseline'])

    df_grouped = df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item'])
    df['baseline_height'] = df_grouped.height[df_grouped["visit"]=='Baseline']



You were almost there.
I suggest grouping by sbj and num_item just like you did, but only after sorting values by sbj, num_item and visit, to make sure that the "Baseline" always appears before the different days ("Day 7", "Day 14", etc...):
df = df[['sbj','num_item','visit','height']]
df.sort_values(['sbj','num_item','visit'])

You can set baseline_height to height:
   df['baseline_height'] = df['height']

Then it is a matter of using the transform method as suggested in this post, in order to populate baseline_height with the first value for each sbj, num_item pair:
   df['baseline_height'] = df.groupby(by = ['sbj', 'num_item']).baseline_height.transform('first')

This yields:
    sbj     num_item    visit       height  baseline_height
0   1       1           Baseline    1.5     1.5
1   1       1           Day 7       2.0     1.5
2   1       1           Day 14      2.5     1.5
3   1       2           Baseline    1.0     1.0
4   1       2           Day 7       1.5     1.0
5   1       2           Day 14      2.0     1.0
6   2       1           Baseline    0.5     0.5
7   2       1           Day 7       1.0     0.5
8   2       1           Day 14      1.5     0.5
9   2       2           Baseline    3.0     3.0
10  2       2           Day 7       3.5     3.0
11  2       2           Day 14      4.0     3.0


Here is a one (three)-liner solution without needing to sort:-
df["baseline_height"] = df.groupby(["sbj", "num_item"])["height"].transform(
    lambda x: x[df["visit"] == "Baseline"].values[0]
)


Thanks!  This works.  Just wondering what the .values[0] is functionally doing here?

when we apply the mask to the grouped df x[df["visit"] == "Baseline"], we get a series of length 1 as a result.
The values call transforms it into a list, and the 0 index retrieves the value from the list.
